# Add page to Scrapy cache

Tags: python, scrapy

While parsing a page, I need to load other pages to collect additional information, but I don't need those pages to be scraped themselves. They are outside the scrape scope and are necessary only for building the scraped content of the parent page. I use `requests` to do this and it works fine:

```
# Code fragment
def parse(self, response):
    for link in links:
        resp = requests.get(link)
        if resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, features='lxml')
            # Append to my metadata
    yield # augmented metadata
```

However, these pages are not cached so when I repeat the scrape using the Scrapy cache, these secondary pages are always reloaded. I would like to manually add them into the Scrapy cache in my parse code. Is it possible to programmatically edit the Scrapy cache?

I thought using the `scrapy.Request()` object might hook me into Scrapy's infrastructure, including caching but I couldn't see a way to fetch the content with it. It seems designed only to be called by Scrapy.

Comment: For caching manually, I don’t think there’s an API. You’ll have to reverse-engineer request caching, and your code could easily break in the future without a warning. I would suggest using `Request`; it is indeed intended to only be called by Scrapy, but that should not be a problem. You seem to believe that it is a problem in your case, so maybe you should post a question about _that_.